# Phonegap app with reactjs

Tags: cordova, reactjs

Has anyone written a phonegap app with reactjs (by facebook)? Any pointers to reference implementation would be appreciated.

Additionally, what data model framework would you suggest to use with reactjs.

Comment: StackOverflow is meant for specific development questions. Check out the Help Center for guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Quora might be a more appropriate platform for software suggestions.

Comment: I did ask it on quora first (without success) - http://www.quora.com/PhoneGap/Has-anyone-written-a-phonegap-app-with-reactjs-Any-pointers-to-reference-implementation-would-be-appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

yes, here is my boilerplate app:
https://github.com/kjda/ReactJs-Phonegap

Answer (score 6):

I have written an application with Phonegap and React.js that runs on both iOS and Android phones and tablets with native-impersonating UI controls.

The number one thing I would recommend is to treat phonegap as a compilation target.

Set up your application like any web-based application using tools like webpack or gulp. This gives you the opportunity to also create Chrome Apps, FxOS Web apps, and customized builds for each platform you support. Take advantage of something like [envify](https://github.com/hughsk/envify) or [webpack.DefinePlugin](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/list-of-plugins#defineplugin) to support this flow.

For data management, Flux is the recommended way, but I’ve found it to be relatively trivial to migrate a medium-sized application from an ad-hoc implementation towards a Flux approach.

Answer (score 1):

hm, its just like using any other js framework. Currently I use backbone's model just create a mixin if model data updates, trigger a component self force_update, or you could trigger specific component to refresh the data by subscribing the events like updateCompoentFrame, updateComponentList.

Also tried the js-model.js but the event on data change doesn't trigger well with reactjs. I might try out flatiron's model next.

They seem to be able to use the same interface for both client and server, seems like to be able to share schemas.

Comment: i know how to do that. I was asking if there is something like ionic framework?