# How to implement offline apps using ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs

I want to make an iPhone/Android app that has some limited capabilities offline. The app should be able to save/cache the state that was used in the last instance it was connected to the internet.

I am wondering if I could do that with ReactJS and how?

If not, is there any other framework that I can use?

Thanks

Comment: It would seem so from some cursory searching: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20697596/phonegap-app-with-reactjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: Since the OP hasn't specified whether she is talking about React Native or not, I assume she is referring to hybrid app development since she mentioned iPhone/Android app.

I am currently making a hybrid application using Apache Cordova + Reactjs + Twitter Bootstrap.
Apache cordova enables wrapping up of HTML, CSS and JavaScript code depending on the platform of the device.

Reactjs is used for creating user interfaces for large applications in which data changes over time. It scales brilliantly because of its virtual DOM.

Twitter Bootstrap is used for styling purposes.

You should go through the [Apache cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/) documentation in detail first, where you will find out how can you save/cache the state using localStorage or other options.

Offline applications with React are extremely efficient and work very fast.

Cordova offers an event called `online` which you can use to check if the app is currently connected to the internet or not.

Short answer: Yes, it's definitely possible what you want.

Comment: Thanks Akshay! That's surely helpful. Apache Cordova sounds promising. My background is in web development so I think it's definitely feasible for me :)

Comment: @novasaint I would like to add that hybrid apps are very much preferred by startups these days and once you get a hold of it, you will realize it is quite powerful. If it helped, please "accept" this answer by clicking on the tick mark next to this answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

React doesn't make any assumptions about how or where you want to use it. If there's a DOM and you can run JS, you can use React.

If there isn't a DOM, you can render to html strings.

It's just a UI library.

Answer (score 1):

Consider Google's polymer.js. It was built to utilize mobile offline experience. This is now called 'progressive applications'.